# Add + sign in front of positive % change

Tags: ios, swift, string, symbols

I am fetching data from an API to be displayed in my iOS app. Some of this data is a percentage so when it is negative it is displayed as -0.98% for example, no problem, but for clarity I'd like positive variations to be displayed as +0.98 and not simply 0.98.

Here is my code when I update the labels:

```
func updateBitcoinUI(with bitcoinInfo: Bitcoin) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.bitcoinPercentageChangeLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f%%", Double(bitcoinInfo.percentChange24h) ?? 0)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add the + symbol to the string when the percentage is positive?

Answer (score 10):

This is what `NumberFormatter` is designed for. Using this rather than hard-coding the format will correctly handle localization in locales that use other percent and separator formats. For example:

```
var formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .percent
formatter.positivePrefix = formatter.plusSign
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let value = 0.0098
formatter.string(for: value)    // +0.98%

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")  // Arabic
formatter.string(for: value)    // ٠٫٩٨ ٪؜+
```

Comment: Or `formatter.string(for: value)` without the cast to NSNumber.

Comment: I knew I needed study the docs harder; I couldn't believe it wasn't in there. Fixed.

Comment: oh…right…didn't follow the docs up to the `Formatter` superclass. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this string format expression "%+.2f%%"

Also: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

Comment: This is better than ternary operator approach, though even this is not localized. E.g. In Germany or France, they'd expect to see "+0,98 %", not "+0.98%", such as offered by `NumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a ternary operator to change the String format to `"+%.2f%%"` when the value is positive.

```
let percentChangeString = "0.98"
guard let percentChange = Double(percentChangeString) else { return }
let percentString = percentChange > 0 ? String(format: "+%.2f%%", percentChange) : String(format: "%.2f%%", percentChange)
```

Output:

> +0.98%

For an input of -0.98, the output is

> -0.98%

Comment: Thanks a lot David, this seems to be what I'm looking for. How can I pass in the value fetched from the API to `let percentChange`? I get `Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'` when I try `let percentChange = bitcoinInfo.percentChange24h`

Comment: @Wizzardzz check my updated answer, since you didn't include the type of `bitcoinInfo.percentChange24h` in your question, I didn't know it was `String`, but I've updated my answer to include the conversion from `String` to `Double` as well. You just have to substitute `bitcoinInfo.percentChange24h` in for `percentChangeString` in the guard statement.