# Localizing percentage values

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a string such as:

> 99 %

According to the [Percent sign Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign), there are at least 13 different variants depending on the user's language.

How can I display a number with the `%` sign that will appear correct according to the user's locale, in Swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47997679/2303865

Answer (score 15):

You can use NumberFormatter to do so. By default it takes user's current locale into account which you can also get using `Locale.current`. And if you wish you could change it as well,

```
func percentFormatted(number: Float, locale: Locale = Locale.current) -> String? {
    let number = (num / 100) as NSNumber
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    numberFormatter.locale = locale
    return numberFormatter.string(from: number)
}

percentFormatted(number: 99.0) // 99% default locale en_US
percentFormatted(number: 99.0, locale: Locale(identifier: "fi_FI")) // 99 %
percentFormatted(number: 99.0, locale: Locale(identifier: "tr_TR")) // %99
```